# get array of dates between two dates, filtered by dayofweek

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have an object as follows:

```
{
  startDate: moment(),
  endDate: moment().add(3, "weeks"),
  friday: true
  monday: true
  saturday: false
  sunday: false
  thursday: false
  tuesday: false
  wednesday: true
}
```

What would be the best way to get an array of dates between the startDate and endDate that match the weekday Booleans?

Expected result: [...Date(), Date(), Date()...]

Comment: Tweak this a little to solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194368/how-to-get-all-sundays-mondays-tuesdays-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can loop from `startDate` to `endDate` using moment [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/).

You can get the day of the week using [`format('dddd')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

If you need use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) to convert moment to JavaScript Date

Here a working sample:

```js
function getDateArray(obj){
  var start = obj.startDate.clone();
  var end = obj.endDate.clone();
  var res = [];
  while(start.isBefore(end)){
    var day = start.format('dddd').toLowerCase();
    if( obj[day] ){
      res.push(start.toDate());
    }
    start.add(1, 'd');
  }
  return res;
}

var obj = {
  startDate: moment(),
  endDate: moment().add(3, "weeks"),
  friday: true,
  monday: true,
  saturday: false,
  sunday: false,
  thursday: false,
  tuesday: false,
  wednesday: true
};
var res = getDateArray(obj);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

moments's diff return number of days between the two dates 
endDate.diff(startDate, 'days')

then forloop from start till start +difference and add one day each
to each day moment().add(1, 'days')