# How to get all dates between two dates given days of the week?

Tags: javascript

First off I know this question is very similar to this one: 
[How to get all sundays/mondays/tuesdays between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194368/how-to-get-all-sundays-mondays-tuesdays-between-two-dates)

What I'm asking is different though, I am trying to make a function where the day of week is a variable and there can be multiple, like this:

```
function findClassDays(daysOfWeek, firstDay, lastDay) {
  const classDays = [];

  return classDays;
}
```

The `firstDay` and `lastDay` are javascript dates and the `daysOfWeek` is an array that contains days of the week in the ddd moment format (ex. array could be `['Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri']`.

How could I find all of the days between those two dates that fall on the `daysOfWeek` provided the days of the week are not known before and there could be multiple? I see on the linked question how it works when you know the day and it is only one but I can't find a solution if the array had any combination of days.

Comment: No as mentioned in my question, that doesn't account for the day of week being a variable and possibly multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on answer of [@JohnHartsock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254528/john-hartsock) we can create the following function which

- populates range of dates between `firstDay` and `lastDay`
- filter dates based on of `daysOfWeek`

```js
var days = {Sun: 0, Mon: 1, Tue: 2, Wed: 3, Thu: 4, Fri:5, Sat:6};

function findClassDays(daysOfWeek, firstDay, lastDay) {
  let classDays = [];
  let rangeDates = getDates(new Date(firstDay), new Date(lastDay));
  classDays = rangeDates.filter(f => daysOfWeek.some((d, i) => days[d]== f.getDay()));
  return classDays;
}

function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = new Array();
  var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
      dateArray.push(new Date (currentDate));
      currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
  }
  return dateArray;
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

console.log(findClassDays(['Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri'], '2019-12-01', '2019-12-15'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size:

```
function findClassDays(daysOfWeek, firstDay, lastDay) {
    var allDays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

    //get indices of days provided
    var firstDayIndex = firstDay.getDay();
    var lastDayIndex = lastDay.getDay();

    //determine which days are acceptable
    var acceptableDays = [];
    for(var i = firstDayIndex; i != lastDayIndex; i = (i + 1) % allDays.length){
        acceptableDays[acceptableDays.length] = allDays[i];
    }
    acceptableDays[acceptableDays.length] = allDays[lastDayIndex];

    //return the intersection (overlap) of daysOfWeek and acceptableDays
    return daysOfWeek.filter(function(d){return acceptableDays.indexOf(d) > -1;});
}
```

OR, if you need the actual date objects and not just the days of the week as strings:

```
function findClassDays(daysOfWeek, firstDay, lastDay){
    var allDays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

    var matchingDates = [];
    while(firstDay.getDay() != lastDay.getDay()){
        //if firstDay is in daysOfWeek
        if(daysOfWeek.indexOf(allDays[firstDay.getDay()]) > -1){
            //add it to matchingDates
            matchingDates[matchingDates.length] = firstDay;
        }

        //increment first day
        firstDay = new Date(firstDay.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }
    //don't forget to check the last day as well
    if(daysOfWeek.indexOf(allDays[lastDay.getDay()]) > -1){
        matchingDates[matchingDates.length] = firstDay;
    }

    return matchingDates;
}
```

Comment: This only returns days of the week? I am looking for the actual dates between the first and last day that fall under the days of the week provided.