# How can I get all the weekdays(Tuesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday) within the year

Tags: javascript, date, weekday

I'm using **Moment.js**. Here is my code:

```
 `const duration = moment.duration(7, 'days');
  const maximumDate = moment().endOf('year');
  const availableDays = [0, 1, 3];
  const days = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  const unavailableDays = availableDays.map((el, i) => {
    return el;  
  }); //will return [0,1,2];

  let initialClosedDays = days.filter(day => {
    return !indexes.includes(day);
  }); //will return [2,4,5,6];

   initialClosedDays &&
    initialClosedDays.map(day =>
      getDayOfYear.push(
        moment(day, 'e')
          .dayOfYear()
          .add(duration.clone())
          .max(maximumDate),
      ),
    );`
```

However, I'm getting .add() is not a function. I know that nesting functions like these won't work but I tried adding the function one by one and still not working. Please help!

Comment: What is the end result you're looking for? An array of the days of the week the venue is not open?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194368/how-to-get-all-sundays-mondays-tuesdays-between-two-dates this could help

Comment: I'm expecting a result of numbers only (i.e. first Wed of the year is "3") if I will get all wednesday for the year, I will only add 7. So the result would be [3,10,17,...]; I know that this was already answered here, however, that is only for one date. What if I would like to get many dates(Wed,Tue,Thur)